# Visual studio not updating project immediately

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a very odd situation where by changes committed to the repository by my colleagues when updated to my local copy of the software, Visual studio doesn't recognise them immediately, and reload. the result (and this is very odd) is that most of the times, I will save my changes without the reloaded projects and will overwrite my colleagues changes. It is so embarrassing that sometimes I am asked why I had to change a piece of code and in reality I hadn't.
Another thing is, when I check in some VS project level changes like when someone added a new class, or form  or anything and continue to work in Visual studio, it will take me at least 5 to 10 minutes before I get the warning that there was some changes and be asked to reload the project etc...

I think there should be a setting somewhere in visual studio to trigger an automatic reload, but can't find it.
This affect me and another person so far but mine is the strangest as it can take up to 30 minutes before a project start reload.

Any Ideas welcome

This is my settings
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working using Source Control, you will need to synchronise your local workspace with the server ("get" the latest code) before any changes by your colleagues will be copied to your PC.

If you don't "get" the latest code before you make changes then you may have to merge your changes with somebody else's, which can be a difficult, time consuming or even dangerous process - especially if you use the default Visual Studio automatic merge process, which usually does the wrong thing, resulting in essentially corrupt code (making it look like you deleted your colleague's works, just as you are describing, for example).

The best way to work with source control is the "little and often" approach:

- Get the latest source code before you start any new work, so that your PC is as up to date as possible.
- It's usually a good practice to "get" the latest code frequently (e.g. I do it first thing every morning) so that any merge conflicts are flagged up and dealt with as early as possible. The longer you wait before merging the worse the merge process tends to get. (Caveat: Check with your build system that the current version of the code on the server is working before you get it - you don't want to get broken code onto your PC as it may stop you being able to work at all).
- Arrange your work as many small incremental steps that can be safely checked in as they are completed (rather than working for 3 months on hundreds of files and then dumping it on the system as one massive change )
- When you are ready to check in, get the latest code, rebuild, and re-test your changes to be sure they still work when integrated with the latest program code. Only check in if everything works well.

Also be aware that when you try to edit a file, the source control provider may automatically "get" the latest version of that file for you (which could cause Visual Studio to tell you it has reloaded the file, and perhaps explain why you say it sometimes takes a while to "update", as it doesn't happen until you start editing a new file that has been changed recently by someone else). If this is the case, then the truth is that you have not "updated" the entire set of source code, only one file - in this case you really need to get all the latest changes to the source code (if you don't you may find it is uncompilable or (even worse), compiles but exhibits undefined behaviours due to only part of the code being up to date)

Lastly, a very good practice when checking in your code is to go through the list of files you are checking in and diff them one by one against the latest server code to see what you have changed. This may sound laborious but it confers several benefits:

- It reminds you what you did, which can sometimes be helpful for filling in the check-in comment to clearly describe all your changes and make sure you don't miss an important note.
- You will easily spot anything that has been screwed up in the merge process - there will be chunks of code that appear to be created or deleted that you know you didn't touch. So you'll be able to discover and fix these problems before you check in rather than annoying your colleagues by "deleting" their changes.
- I find this very useful for finding temporary debugging code that I have forgotten to take out before I check in.
- Sometimes you may even do a double-take on a bit of code you are about to check in and think "huh? why did I do that?". And then you might decide to re-examine and possibly even rewrite the code you thought was good to go.

Final Note: The options you show in your edit *only* relate to changes that are made to the files *on your PC* by another program *on your PC*. If another user makes a change and checks it in to source control, these options will have *no effect*. It is only when your Source Control system copies those changes to your PC's hard drive that you might see Visual Studio reacting to those changes (depending on how well your source control system is integrated with VS).

Comment: I have market your reply as an answer because it provides some good practices

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure the problem is Visual Studio (e.g. the file really *has* changed on the disk but you don't see it in Visual Studio)

Make sure that the `Detect when file is changed` option is checked.

`Tools > Options > Environment > Documents > Detect when file is changed outside the environment`

[image]

Comment: I have that checked but the auto-load changes, if saved isn't checked? should I check that one?

Comment: The Auto-Load option will reload the file without giving a warning message (but with the newer content).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sometimes getting an alert to reload your project due to external changes means you already have the settings required to detect file changes in Visual Studio.

However, reloading of project/solution will only be triggered if the .csproj (or .vbproj) or .sln file was changed.

By the way, are you using some version control system? It seems that you are just sharing the solution and editing simultaneously.

Comment: forgot to mention we use SVN, which cause the problem when we have so many changes going around we are at least five dev on a project and so far I have offended two trying my best not to offend the remaining three

Comment: In that case, close communication is necessary within your team. Everyone should make sure to update their working copy before committing anything so that you can resolve conflicts individually. But then conflicts cannot be avoided sometimes.